# Weird log in menu after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, updates

I am using Toshiba satellite c55I laptop and i have just upgraded to the newest version of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit. I did this for the added security benefits of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, and I have experienced an odd black-fuzz after entering my password when logging in. It seams to crash but then moments later boot smoothly up to my desktop.

I had some issue with my login screen on 14.04.1 where my desktop background didn't load. As well as being slow to boot to my desktop. Now its the same issue but with a bit of black-fuzz within the screen.This doesn't happen after the first boot up only when the computer is booted for the first time. After that its business as usual.This does not seem to effect the computer in any way, shape, or form. if i might add the laptop runs great with the OS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/
And can you make a video or take a picture, because what you're describing could just be an external monitor switching resolutions...

Comment: i fixed it the other day thanks for the help though i just dont know how to delete a question thats why its still up

Comment: Fantastic!  Answer your own question on how you fixed it, so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more *and other people can benefit from your experience*! That's what this site is all about!  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I have to use the pre-set wallpapers so that this won't happen. Now it boots up properly.

Comment: Were the non-preset wallpapers located on a partition that isn't mounted during boot?

Comment: I think so but i'm not sure. Lucky for me Ubuntu comes with some nice pre-set wallpapers so i found on i enjoyed

Comment: Well, what's the output of `df -P [PATH] | awk 'NR==2 { print $6 }'`, where `[PATH]` is the path or folder of your custom wallpaper, and does it appear in `/etc/fstab`? All-in-one: `grep -Fe "$(df -P [PATH] | awk 'NR==2 { print $6 }')" /etc/fstab`

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)